# Entity Framework - Multiple navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, navigation-properties

I started working with Entity Framework and I have one BIG problem. I want a many-to-many relation between entities `User` and `Role`.

So I created 3 tables `User`, `Role`, `UserRoles`

[image: db]

Next I created 3 entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> CreatedRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual int RoleId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public virtual int UserRoleId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual int CreateUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreateUser { get; set; }
}
```

I want to separate mapped user from created user. And In this step Entity Framework start to throw a bugs.

Next I want navigate from `User` object to his mapped roles and to his created mappings.

Can I configure Entity Framework to do these things?

Comment: I think it is good relation in DB so I want create good Entities in .NET

Answer (score 1):

You should apply InverseProperty attribute:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("CreateUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> CreatedRoles { get; set; }
}
```